# USB CDC communication freeze on Windows

Tags: windows, embedded, usb, cdc

I have problem with communication via USB CDC with Windows. On Linux or Mac everything work good.
So, when I try to connect to my COM port I get notification from PUTTY "Unable to open communication to COM2. Unable to configure port.

It is my own device based on Rx63n uC, I transmit in FullSpeed standard, packet in size less than 64 bytes. I'm used 2 endpoints for bulk transfer IN/OUT.
In USBLyzer I got information thatSTALL packet is received from my device after error (USBD_STATUS_CANCELED). 
I used driver from Windows 10 usbser.sys.

Any ideas what is wrong?

I forgot to add that in USBLyzer I see a lot of my packets, and after transferred some data it generate error as above.

Comment: Is it code level problem.

Comment: @VedPrakash But could you help me where should I searching? I spend on this 2 days and don't know what is wrong

Comment: i will try to solve your problem.

Comment: don't be rude, i want just a hint or something which show me where I should searching.
It's only sample with little modifications. Clean sample isn't woking too on windows.

Comment: First validate your device by running at least the the "chapter 9" tests in USB20CV test suite at http://www.usb.org/developers/tools/usb20_tools/.

Comment: Presumably Get/SetCommState() does not do what it is supposed to do.  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET/SET_Xxxx on the device driver end.  Handling the DCB does not make much sense for a USB device, but you have to pretend that it all works anyway.